# Get element size after recursive rendering react

Tags: reactjs, get, size, rendering, element

after a recursive rendering (2secondes), i want to get the height of the container of the recursive elements using componentDidMount, but the return value is always 0.
I need to do this because i have a div with an absolute position and i have to manage its height.

See bellow my componentDidMount function :

```
componentDidMount(){

    // get the height of the container
    let CalGridHeight = $("#ui-body-container-bottom").height();

    //Update State
    this.setState({
        GridHeight : CalGridHeight,
    });

}
```

Any idea to get the size of an element after the rendering (when the app is completely displayed on screen) ? 
I tried a recursive function inside componentDidMount waiting CalGridHeight > 0 but it's not working...

I tried with react ref but it's the same issue

```
componentDidMount(){

    console.log(this.refBodyBottom)
    console.log(this.refBodyBottom.current.clientHeight)

}
```

in my first console : i can get the element with all the attributs, and i have the .clientHeight = 17000 but in the second console the .clientHeight = 0 ...

Thank you for your help !

**I found a temporary solution using setinterval**, waiting the best solution :

```
componentDidMount(){

    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.refBodyBottom.current.clientHeight > 0){
            this.setState({GridHeight : this.refBodyBottom.current.clientHeight + "px"})
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
    }
    , 1000);

 }
```

Comment: Mixing React and JQuery is really an anti-pattern.   You will want to look into React Refs to solve this.  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Keith i tried with react refs but it exactly the same issue .clientHeight = 0 px // i added the code in my post